# How to display image in Yii framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am new to Yii framework. I want display an image.

I am getting below error:

> ERROR: Alias "application.extensions.seqimage.SeqImage" is invalid.
>   Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
>   please any one can help me out.

Comment: do you have the extension SeqImage installed/uploaded to your extensions folder? Could you please post the code where you call the widget?

Comment: Can you show us the directory structure to file `SeqImage.php` from `protected` dir

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with you alias's. Try use `ext.seqimage.SeqImage` instead `application.extensions.seqimage.SeqImage`

Comment: Alias "ext.seqimage.SeqImage" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.   this kind of error is comming

Comment: Ok, can you show me result of `Yii::setPathOfAlias('ext.seqimage.SeqImage')`?

Answer (score 0):

you can also display image tags using [CHtml](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail)

```
$image = Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/loader.gif';

echo CHtml::image($image , $detail->idProduct0->Name , array(
   'style' => 'max-height: 128px;',
)); ?>
```